# is vscode remote-ssh inception possible?

Tags: visual-studio-code, remote-debugging

I am connecting remote linux and developing some application. To run the application I need to connect to another host for debugging due to resource availibility using `srun` command.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like partial inception is possible using below in launch.json.

```json
"miDebuggerServerAddress": "remoteHostname:9091",
```

And running the command on remote host as:

```sh
user@remoteHostname $ gdbserver :9091 ./myapplication arguments to my program
```